# #include <Python.h> - compilation terminated on Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I am trying to install 4Suite-XML 1.02 on my Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. I downloaded the tar.gz, extracted it, opened a terminal in the extracted directory, shifted to root shell with `sudo su`, and ran `python setup.py install`. I get this as output:

```
running install
running build
running config
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Ft.Lib.number' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c          Ft/Lib/src/number.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Ft/Lib/src/number.o
Ft/Lib/src/number.c:7:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually Linux distributions split programming language run-times to two packages and Python is no exception.

- `python` - Python code runtime
- `python-dev` - Development files, libraries and headers. Needed to install any native extensions. Aimed for developers. Something that integrates Python to "native" C libraries. Python code is portable across operating systems, C code is not. C code must be recompiled to every operating system.

You need to install related `python-dev` package which contains C headers necessary to compile Python native extensions. This command is usually `sudo apt install python-dev` on Debian based distributions. I have not checked the actual command for Mint Linux, but I assume it to be the same.

Also please read the official Python package installation guide https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html - usually `sudo` installations and `python setup.py install` are unnecessary. `pip install --user` command should be able to download, extract and install the package for you.

Comment: How do I find the "related python-dev package"? I do not understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Also, I tried using pip command (with sudo as I want it installed not just for my user). I got another error... Should I post that here?

Comment: One more thing: What do you mean by native extensions? I'm sorry, but I am unfamiliar with a great deal of terminology.

Comment: Something that integrates Python to "native" C libraries. Python code is portable across operating systems, C code is not. C code must be recompiled to every operating system.

Comment: @Rohan: Also no worries - let's hope this clears everything out.

Comment: It recommends moving this to chat, so I'll do so, because I have a few more questions, if that's okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99666/discussion-between-rohan-and-mikko-ohtamaa).

Comment: In Debian 9 installing manually `setuptools` instead of setup.py works. `python3 -m pip install setuptools==41.6.0`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev`